# Local replica of RDS database

Tags: replication, mysql, database-replication, amazon-rds

I've been doing some research for the past hour or so and I've been hearing some conflicting information regarding the replication of Amazon RDS databases. My database is pretty big, 15 tables with a total size of 4 GB. So, basically, is it possible for me to create a local replica of a remote RDS InnoDB or does Amazon not allow it?

Comment: What is your intention? Having a local test environment similar to your RDS-backed environment or adding failover?

Comment: @Viccari Having a local test environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create replicas of an RDS but only as another RDS. You can't do a replica on an EC2 or a local machine.