# Amazon RDS replica

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I'm currently migrating my servers on Amazon EC2 and RDS and I can't find out how to create a replica of my production DB instance to a development DB instance.

Basically what I would like to do is have a replication occurring everyday or week to be able to work on almost actual data on my development environment.

Of course the multi-AZ option wouldn't work in this context since this is not for fail-over and the replication should only go in one direction (prod -> dev) to prevent any insertion of test data or any loss on the production server.

Comment: I've found this post which is quite similar but it doesn't really respond to my question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553371/local-replica-of-rds-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your database is rather small, you can run the following command from a cron job:

`mysqldump --host=<RDS endpoint> --user=<username> --password=<password> mydatabase > | mysql --host=<dev server or dev RDS instance> --user=<username> --password=<password> mydatabase`

This will dump the "mydatabase" DB from RDS and pipe it into a "mydatabase" DB on another host.  You can't run cron jobs on RDS, so this will have to run on a stand-alone server or EC2 instance.

Comment: Thank you @jamieb for your response. It worked for me with a little change in the syntax :
mysqldump --host=<RDS endpoint> --user=<username> --password=<password> mydatabase > dump.sql && mysql --host=<dev server or dev RDS instance> --user=<username> --password=<password> mydatabase <dump.sql && rm dump.sql

Comment: I also found this very useful page explaining how to write a script in PHP that does exactly this : http://faq.1and1.com/web_space__access/mysql/13.html

Answer (score 0):

I would check out http://www.skeddly.com/

I know it can do automated RDS snapshots, perhaps you can set up a custom action type to load the snapshots on your Dev RDS instance somehow.